# PHP - how to make sure each socket requests are sent?

Tags: php, sockets, zend-framework, ubuntu

I have this code from 8AM till 10PM Monday to Friday used to open DOOR and CLOSE DOOR of the main entrance.

Every single day i have problem with PHP its unable to send the command from 8AM till 12PM is fine but after that starts strange problems, then to fix it i need to always reboot the PHP running machine and then again few hours it works fine again it stop working.

in remote location when i do tcpdump trace i do not get any packets coming from PHP following code sometimes and sometimes i get. What is causing it?

Can anyone kindly please share what is happening why PHP cant send each and every TCP command requests?

Unite test:

```
$reject = new Application_Model_TCPClient('ip address',58888);
$reject->sendNoWait("connect");
```

Zend framework: Models:

```
<?php
class Application_Model_TCPClient {

  private $buffer = null;
  private $fullbuffer = null;
  private $socket = null;
  private $host = null;
  private $post = null;

  public function __construct($host, $port = 58888) {
    $this->host = $host;
    $this->port = $port;
    $this->connect();
  }

  public function __destruct() {
    //$this->disconnect();
  }

  public function connect() {
    $this->socket = @fsockopen($this->host, $this->port, $errno, $errstr, 1);
  }

  public function disconnect() {
    fclose($this->socket);
  }

  public function clearBuffer() {
    $this->buffer = '';
  }

  public function getBuffer() {
    return $this->fullbuffer;
  }

  public function sendNoWait($cmd) {
    if (!$this->socket) {
      $report = "fail";
    } else {
      fputs($this->socket, "$cmd\n");
      $this->fullbuffer = "success";
      $this->disconnect();
      $report = "success";
    }
    switch ($report) {
      case "fail":
        return "fail";
        break;
      case "success":
        return $this->getBuffer();
        break;
    }
  }



}
```

Comment: LOL!  Maybe you can fool PHP by changing the computer's clock?  :)

Comment: Could this be a PHP bug or Kernel BUG? kernel: `$ uname -a
Linux sun-Alienware-X51 3.11.0-14-generic #21-Ubuntu SMP Tue Nov 12 17:04:55 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux` php: `PHP 5.5.3-1ubuntu2.1 (cli) (built: Dec 12 2013 04:24:35) `